# ASP.NET Canceling download

Tags: asp.net

I have a download button in my page from which if the button is clicked, a dialog popup in firefox or internet explorer appears saying, "Do you want to open or save file?" .. The popup is from the browser itself.

The scenario is that, if the user clicks logout on the site, is it possible to fail the download if he clicks saves or open file. It seems like it cannot be prevented for me..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it's possible. try to search for "asp.net track download success". The basic idea is to read the file a little at a time and then check for user status before streaming to the output buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the request for the file is authenticated at the time it was clicked and is still valid after a logout.